# KnockoutJS not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I cant seem to get the binding to work on my KnockoutJS app.

JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/maylortaylor/pfqnkj17/

Here is the format of my JSON (generated by using `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.forms,null,2)"></pre>`)

```
[
  {
    "formTitle": "formTitle",
    "formDescription": "formDesc",
    "fieldTemplates": [
      {
        "fieldId": "text1",
        "title": "title",
        "description": "description fieldTemplate",
        "isReq": true
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "text2",
        "title": "ttitle22",
        "description": "description fieldTemplate 2",
        "isReq": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is how i am trying to call it in the page

```
<div id="MiddleColumn">
            <input data-bind="textInput: $root.formTitle" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="span8 hideOffFocus input-full large-type">
        <input data-bind="textInput: formDescription" type="text" placeholder="Description" class="hideOffFocus input-full">
</div
```

neither of those bindings work.

I create the `forms` object here

```
var FormModel = function (forms) {
    var self = this;

    self.forms = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(forms, function (form) {
        return {
            formTitle: form.formTitle, formDescription: form.formDescription,
            fieldTemplates: ko.observableArray(form.fieldTemplates) };
    }));

};

ko.applyBindings(new FormModel(initialData));
```

Comment: I wouldn't post this as a SO question, because your own code shows errors if you run web browser's debugger (i.e. Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug), and the debugger should be enough for you to fix the issue. In the other hand, it seems like you expect an observable array to turn object properties into observable too, and this isn't how KO works!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer is 100% right . you can check chrome console you find undefined error i.e `$root` is missing in the binding . moreover use `mapping` to turn plain arrays to observables . tip : if you change in textbox as it's not observable value wont get updated

Answer (score 1):

i hope your are expecting something like this

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/rt2pd3rt/)**

Now if you change something in textboxes in preview you can see automatic updates i.e `mapping` does make things back to ko way .

**View Model :**

```
 var mapping = {
        'fieldTemplates': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new FormModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    }

function FormModel(forms) {
        var self = this;
        self.forms = ko.observableArray();
        ko.mapping.fromJS(forms, mapping, self);

       // other stuff

       }
```

**View :**

```
<div id="MiddleColumn">
    <input data-bind="textInput: $root.formTitle" type="text" />
    <input data-bind="textInput: $root.formDescription" type="text"/><br/>
    <div data-bind="foreach:$root.fieldTemplates">
        <span data-bind="text:fieldId"></span> 
         <span data-bind="text:title"></span>
         <span data-bind="text:description"></span>
         <span data-bind="text:isReq"></span>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```